# AngularJS dynamic image sources

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<img src="{{ twt.display }}"/>
```

I have the above image tag where the src is in the scope but when I look at the browser console log it shows the following

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://example.com/%7B%7Btwt.display%7D%7D".

The images do show as intended but I wanted to know if there was a way of stopping this message appearing?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `ng-src` to avoid strange undeliverable requests being made by browser.

Once the expression in `ng-src` is resolved, it will update the `src` for the tag,

```
<img ng-src="{{twt.display}}"/>
```